# PHP class function not working

Tags: php

I'm new to PHP and web scripting in general so this a newb question.

Currently i'm a creating an instance to an object, yet when I call the constructor
the script slienty shuts down... it doesn't call the next function and I don't know why.
Any help would be welcome.

Here is the code.

```
<?php
class product {
    var $ssProductName;
    var $ssVendorName;
    var $ssDescr;
    var $ssURI;

    // Clean constructor, strings must be cleaned before use
    function __construct($ssProd, $ssVendor, $ssD, $ssU) {
        $this->$ssProductName = $ssProd;
        $this->$ssVendorName = $ssVendor;
        $this->$ssDescr = $ssD;
        $this->$ssURI = $ssU;
    }

    // print a table of the values
    function DisplayOneEntry() {

        echo '<table border="1">
                    <tr>
                    <td>'.$this->$ssProductName.'</td>
                    <td>'.$this->$ssVendorName.'</td>
                    <td>'.$this->$ssDescr.'</td>
                    <td>'.$this->$ssURI.'</td>
                    </tr>
                    </table>';
    }

}

echo "<HTML>";
echo "A";
$newP = new product("Redhat", "Redhat corp", "Leader in", "www.redhat.com");
echo "B";
$newP->DisplayOneEntry();

echo "</HTML>";
?>
```

But the output is just:

```
<HTML>
A
```

Then nothing else.

This is running on a hosting provider using php 5.2.9 and Apache 2.2.

Comment: I take it you forgot the leading <?php ? Btw, the trailing ?> is not necessary.

Comment: It looks like you have display_errors set to Off, or error_reporting showing nothing, or both of these problems.

Comment: I think the var keyword is deprecated in 5. Turn your errors on and provide those please :) through error_reporting(E_ALL)

Comment: There also seems to be missing ' on the end of your <td>
You need to escape the line return

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You need to access the member variables with:

```
$this->variableName
```

Not:

```
$this->$variableName
```

Comment: Thankyou all for your help. And yes now I have display_error turned on. :-)

Answer (score 3):

```
    $this->$ssProductName = $ssProd;
```

should be

```
    $this->ssProductName = $ssProd;
```

no $ after the ->

Answer (score 1):

The syntax `$this->$foo` is a [variable variable](http://docs.php.net/manual/en/language.variables.variable.php) referencing the class attribute with the name of the value of `$foo`. So if `$foo` has the value `bar`, `$this->$foo` would reference `$foo->bar` and not `$this->foo`.

So just remove the `$` after `$this->` and it should work.

Answer (score 0):

That is because your php script is erroneous. To catch such errors, you should run it on a debugging server (with `display_errors` set to `On`) or use other logging methods.

However, the main problem is you are accessing object members the wrong way; there's no second dollar sign. Instead of

```
$this->$ssProductName = $ssProd;
```

use

```
$this->ssProductName = $ssProd;
```